# .NET Core 1.1 web api in memory caching

Tags: caching, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to cache some information using in memory caching option in .net core web api. Need to get some information from the database in the startup and cache it for 24 hrs. All the controllers in the API should read the data from this cache.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add MemoryCache in configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

Then use the IMemoryCache provided byt the assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory

```
public interface IMemoryCache : IDisposable
{
    bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value);
    ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key);
    void Remove(object key);
}
```

Then Inject IMemoryCache anywhere in your classes

```
public YourClassConstructor(IMemoryCache cache)
{
   this.cache = cache;
}
```

You can set your cache like this (for example in your BLL) :

```
cache.Set(“Key”, DataToCache);
```

And in your controllers you can read your cache like this:

```
[HttpGet()]
public string Get()
{
   return cache.Get<TypeOfYourCachedData>(CacheKey);
}
```